not all images can be displayed

Here is my code for get image:
Image.network('http://10.0.2.2:8000/${widget.product.imageUrl}',               fit: BoxFit.cover),
and the error:
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following HttpException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Connection closed while receiving data, uri = http://10.0.2.2:8000/uploads/products/0-1713659504.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      \_HttpIncoming.listen.\<anonymous closure\> (dart:\_http/http_impl.dart:442:7)
http_impl.dart:442
#11     \_HttpParser.\_reportBodyError (dart:\_http/http_parser.dart:1201:22)
http_parser.dart:1201
#12     \_HttpParser.\_onDone (dart:\_http/http_parser.dart:899:9)
http_parser.dart:899
#20     \_Socket.\_onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2454:21)
socket_patch.dart:2454
#27     new \_RawSocket.\<anonymous closure\> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1943:35)
socket_patch.dart:1943
#28     \_NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1372:18)
socket_patch.dart:1372
(elided 25 frames from dart:async)

Image provider: NetworkImage("http://10.0.2.2:8000/uploads/products/0-1713659504.png", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("http://10.0.2.2:8000/uploads/products/0-1713659504.png", scale: 1.0)

I tried to use this but didn't work:
CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/${image['image']}',   placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(), // Tampilkan indicator loading   errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error), ),
and this
Another exception was thrown: HttpException: Connection closed while receiving data, uri =
but still didn't work.
How can it be fixed to do this?

Check if you have enabled intrnet permision.
Go to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
and check if you have this line of code:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

Happy Codding :)

I already have  in AndroidManifest.xml still did'n work, there are some images that cannot be displayed

U mean some images displayed well and some not?

yes some images displaye but some error The following HttpException was thrown resolving an image codec: Connection closed while receiving data, uri = http://10.0.2.2:8000/uploads/products/0-1713659504.png

URL is incorrect. I can not open it even with my browser, how do u expect app to load an image that the URL is incorrect???

Test with this url:     https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BM2MyNjYxNmUtYTAwNi00MTYxLWJmNWYtYzZlODY3ZTk3OTFlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@.V1_UY268_CR1,0,182,268_AL.jpg

the url is a localhost

you can use like this code to handle the images
class app {
  static String icon = "assets/icon.jpg";
}    

Container(
                      width: 100.0,
                      height: 100.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: app.icon.startsWith('http')
                              ? NetworkImage(app.icon) as ImageProvider
                              : AssetImage(app.icon) as ImageProvider,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                    ),


I've tried but it's same:)
